# How can I read äöüß in java?

Tags: java

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    List<String> knownWordsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> wordsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> newWordsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String toFile = "";

    public void readKnownWordsFile() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream2 = new FileInputStream("knownWords.txt");

            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream2, "UTF-8"));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                knownWordsArrayList.add(strLine.toLowerCase());
            }
            HashSet h = new HashSet(knownWordsArrayList);
            // h.removeAll(knownWordsArrayList);
            knownWordsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(h);
            // for (int i = 0; i < knownWordsArrayList.size(); i++) {
            // System.out.println(knownWordsArrayList.get(i));
            // }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    public void readFile() {
        try {
            // Open the file that is the first
            // command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Smallville 4x02.de.srt");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

            String strLine;

            String numberedLineRemoved = "";
            String strippedInput = "";
            String[] words;
            String trimmedString = "";
            String temp = "";
            // Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                temp = strLine.toLowerCase();
                // Print the content on the console
                numberedLineRemoved = numberedLine(temp);
                strippedInput = numberedLineRemoved.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
                if ((strippedInput.trim().length() != 0) || (!strippedInput.contains("")) || (strippedInput.contains(" "))) {
                    words = strippedInput.split("\\s+");
                    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                        if (words[i].trim().length() != 0) {
                            wordsArrayList.add(words[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            HashSet h = new HashSet(wordsArrayList);
            h.removeAll(knownWordsArrayList);
            newWordsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(h);

            // HashSet h = new HashSet(wordsArrayList);
            // wordsArrayList.clear();
            // newWordsArrayList.addAll(h);

            for (int i = 0; i < newWordsArrayList.size(); i++) {
                toFile = newWordsArrayList.get(i) + ".\n";
//              System.out.println(newWordsArrayList.get(i) + ".");
                System.out.println();
            }

            System.out.println(newWordsArrayList.size());
            // Close the input stream
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String numberedLine(String string) {
        if (string.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return string;
        }
    }

    public void writeToFile() {
        try {
            // Create file
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(toFile);
            // Close the output stream
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.readKnownWordsFile();
        test.readFile();
        test.writeToFile();

    }

}
```

How can I read äöüß from file? 
Would the string.toLowercase() handle these properly as well? 
And when I go to print words containing any of äöüß, how can I print the word properly?
When I print to console I get 
AuÃŸerdem
weiÃŸ
for Außerdem
weiß
How can I fix this?

I tried:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

But now I'm getting aufkl?ren instead of aufklären and its messing up in other places as well.

Updated the code to see if it would print on the file properly, but I'm just getting one in the file.

Comment: Learn about Unicode and UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: You can read it from a file, by reading it from the file; this question makes no sense.

Comment: @duffymo Or any other characterset containing these characters...

Comment: @PradeepSimha Those are "Umlaute" or "Umlauts" (in english) that are for example used in german. Can be read with UTF-8 encoding very well though.

Comment: If you show us how you currently do it, we'll be able to show you what's wrong. Otherwise, this is not a real question.

Comment: Show some code, you're probably reading a file using the wrong charset.

Comment: Have a look at `toLowerCase(Locale locale)` method and at Class `Locale`.

Comment: use `new InputStreamReader(in2, "UTF-8")` or the appropiate encoding of your file.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for:
new InputStreamReader(in2, "UTF-8")

Comment: Well this didn't excatly fix the problem.

Comment: Seems like you need to find out which encoding has been used to save the file's data. Other common encodings for german text are "ISO-8859-1" and "cp1252".

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read files using the charset which was used to create the file.  If you're on a windows machine, that's probably cp1252.  So:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "Cp1252"));
```

If that doesn't work, most text editors are capable of telling you what encoding is used for a given document.